# CreateFileMapping() returning "already exists" even after reboot; how to remove old Named Shared Memory?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a series of Slave exe's controlled by a Master exe via usage of Named Shared Memory created with CreateFileMapping() and MapViewOfFile().

I was debugging the Master via Visual Studio, and when I got what I needed I simply told Visual Studio to "stop debugging". Bad move, because that Named Shared Memory was left active, and it is still there after reboots!

I've tried recognizing the Named Shared Memory via looking at the error code, seeing it was 183 (already exists) and asking for the existing Named Shared Memory, but that fails.

I'd be happy either way: remove/delete it when found to already exist, or reuse it when found to already exist. Currently, I'm stuck. I guess I could create a different name, but that damn one that already exists will probably just linger there forever...

Anyway, here's the C++ class defining my Named Shared Memory control logic:

```
enum ServerSharedMemReturnCodes {
    Success,                    // everything worked!
    SharedMemAlreadyGrabbed,    // EnableSharedMemoryAccess() error: _mapFile was not NULL!
    OpenFileMappingFailed,      // EnableSharedMemoryAccess() error: OpenFileMapping() filed!
    MapViewOfFileFailed         // EnableSharedMemoryAccess() error: MapViewOfFile() filed!
};

class ServerSharedMem {
public:
    ServerSharedMem() {
        _mapFile         = NULL;
        _serverCommLinks = NULL;
    }
    ~ServerSharedMem() {
        // Deactivate(); called explicitly at shutdown rather than here
    }

    /* our Named Shared Memory needs to be "activated" by the Master (installed to shared virtual memory). This does that. */
    inline int Activate( void ) {
        char *caller = "ServerSharedMem::Activate";

        if (_mapFile != NULL) {
            DebugMessage( caller, "Named Shared Memory already activated!" );
            return false;
        }

        TCHAR smName[]      = TEXT(CEX_SHAREDMEM_NAME);
        int   sharedMemSize = sizeof(ServerCommLink) * CEX_MAX_SERVER_COUNT;

        // debug logic: print out size and name:
        size_t convertedChars = 0;
        char   bsjnk[1024];
        errno_t err = wcstombs_s( &convertedChars, bsjnk, 1024, smName, sizeof(smName));
        if (err != 0) {
            DebugMessage( caller, "wcstombs_s  failed!" );
        } 
        char bsjnk2[1024];
        sprintf_s( bsjnk2, 1024, "sharedMemSize is '%d' bytes and smName is '%s'", sharedMemSize, bsjnk );
        DebugMessage( caller, bsjnk2 ); // size is 16832, name is "Global\CEX_ActiveTasks"


        // let's create a Named Shared Memory block:
        _mapFile = CreateFileMapping( INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,   // request a paging file
                                      NULL,                   // default security
                                      PAGE_READWRITE | SEC_COMMIT, // read/write access and hold entirely in RAM
                                      0,                      // high-order DWORD of max file size
                                      sharedMemSize,          // low-order DWORD of max file size
                                      smName );               // name of our named shared memory
        if (_mapFile == NULL) {
            DebugMessage( caller, "failed to create Named Shared Memory!" );

            DWORD errCode = GetLastError();
            if (errCode == 183) { // already exists! we did not shutdown cleanly
               DebugMessage( caller, "It appears to already exist! Attempting to grab it!" );
               ServerSharedMemReturnCodes retCode = EnableSharedMemoryAccess();
               if (retCode == Success) {
                  DebugMessage( caller, "Yes! Got it!" );
                  for (int i = 0; i < CEX_MAX_SERVER_COUNT; i++) {
                      _serverCommLinks[i].Init();
                      _serverCommLinks[i].SetServerId( i );
                  }
                  return true;
               }
               static CHAR errBuffer[CEX_CMDBUFFER_SIZE];
                va_list     errArgs[256];
                FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,NULL,errCode,0,errBuffer,CEX_CMDBUFFER_SIZE,errArgs);
                DebugMessage( caller, errBuffer );
                sprintf_s( errBuffer, CEX_CMDBUFFER_SIZE, "error code is '%d'", errCode );
                DebugMessage( caller, errBuffer ); // still 183, already exists
            }
            /*
            static CHAR errBuffer[CEX_CMDBUFFER_SIZE];
            va_list     errArgs[256];
            FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,NULL,errCode,0,errBuffer,CEX_CMDBUFFER_SIZE,errArgs);
            DebugMessage( caller, errBuffer );
            sprintf_s( errBuffer, CEX_CMDBUFFER_SIZE, "error code is '%d'", errCode );
            DebugMessage( caller, errBuffer ); */
            return false;
        }
        else {
            _serverCommLinks = (ServerCommLink *)MapViewOfFile(_mapFile, FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 0);
            if (_serverCommLinks == NULL) {
                CloseHandle(_mapFile);
                _mapFile = NULL;
                DebugMessage( caller, "MapViewOfFile() failed!" );
                return false;
            }
            else {
                for (int i = 0; i < CEX_MAX_SERVER_COUNT; i++) {
                    _serverCommLinks[i].Init();
                    _serverCommLinks[i].SetServerId( i );
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    /* upon program shutdown, Named Shared Memory needs to be removed from Shared Virtual Memory. This does that. */
    inline void Deactivate( void ) {
        char *caller = "ServerSharedMem::Deactivate";
        if (_mapFile) {
            if (_serverCommLinks) {
                UnmapViewOfFile( _serverCommLinks );
                _serverCommLinks = NULL;
                DebugMessage( caller, "Unmapped Named Shared Memory view." );
            }
            CloseHandle(_mapFile);
            _mapFile = NULL;
            DebugMessage( caller, "Closed Named Shared Memory handle." );
        }
    }

    /* Slaves use this to gain access to the Named Shared Memory setup by their Master */
    inline ServerSharedMemReturnCodes EnableSharedMemoryAccess( void ) {
        if (_mapFile != NULL) {
            return SharedMemAlreadyGrabbed;
        }
        TCHAR smName[] = TEXT(CEX_SHAREDMEM_NAME);
        _mapFile = OpenFileMapping( FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE, FALSE, smName );
        if (_mapFile == NULL) {
            return OpenFileMappingFailed;
        }
        else {
            _serverCommLinks = (ServerCommLink *)MapViewOfFile( _mapFile, FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 0 );
            return Success;
        }
    }

    /* Slaves use this to release their hold on their view of the Named Shared Memory */
    inline void ReleaseSharedMemoryAccess( void ) {
        char *caller = "ServerSharedMem::ReleaseSharedMemoryAccess";
        if (_mapFile != NULL) {
            if (_serverCommLinks != NULL) {
                UnmapViewOfFile( _serverCommLinks );
                _serverCommLinks = NULL;
                DebugMessage( caller, "Unmapped Named Shared Memory view." );
            }
            else DebugMessage( caller, "No active Named Shared Memory view!" );
            CloseHandle(_mapFile);
            DebugMessage( caller, "Closed Named Shared Memory handle." );
        }
        else DebugMessage( caller, "No Named Shared Memory!" );
    }

    /* pass in a return code, get back a string describing the code */
    inline char *ReturnCodeInfo( ServerSharedMemReturnCodes code ) {
        switch (code) {
        case Success:                 return "Success.";
        case SharedMemAlreadyGrabbed: return "Shared memory access has already been enabled.";
        case OpenFileMappingFailed:   return "Unable to open Named Shared Memory!";
        case MapViewOfFileFailed:     return "Unable to map view of Named Shared Memory!";
        default:                      return "Unknown return code!!!";
        }
    }

    inline int Active( void ) { return(_serverCommLinks ? true : false); }

    /* returns the requested server;s communication link if Named Shared Memory is activated/enabled */
    inline ServerCommLink *GetServerCommLink( int serverId ) {
        if (!_serverCommLinks)
            return NULL;
        if ((serverId >= 0) && (serverId < CEX_MAX_SERVER_COUNT)) {
            return &_serverCommLinks[serverId];
        }
        return NULL;
    }

private:
    HANDLE         _mapFile;           // our Named Shared Memory handle
    ServerCommLink *_serverCommLinks;  // will point to shared memory, an array of size CEX_MAX_SERVER_COUNT
};
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `OpenFileMapping` from inside your error code 183 handling routine and seeing if you can get a handle to it? Apologies if you have, but it's not in your code in the question.

Comment: Yes. If you follow the errCode==183 logic, it calls EnableSharedMemoryAccess(), another method in the same class, and that tries OpenFileMapping() to get the already existing Named Shared Memory. And that fails too.

Comment: I just tried using a different name, just to see if I can continue working, but that fails too. Something else must be taking place, because this logic has been working for weeks... I did just to a Windows Update... hope some updated OS whatever is not the cause...

Comment: Have you tried a name without the ":" chars? I'm not sure those are valid.

Comment: @JoelLucsy: I don't see any ':' characters being used in the mapping name (then again, I don't see a definition for `CEX_SHAREDMEM_NAME`, either).  Are you referring to the 'caller' variables?  Those are for debug logging.

Comment: Named kernel objects, like file mappings, DO NOT persist across reboots.  If you are seeing the mapping exist after a reboot, it is because something else created the mapping anew after the reboot before your app tried to access it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ah, right, my bad.

Comment: You can always use Process Explorer's Find Handle `Ctrl+F` to locate your named mapping and the process to which it belongs. Be sure it re-created the mapping after reboot (as opposed for it to survive the boot itself).

Comment: @JoelLucsy: I placed the mapping name in a comment. It's "Global\CEX_ActiveTasks".

Comment: Okay, I just tried ProcessExplorer. My named mapping does not exist. I suspected as such when I tried testing with different names. So, what else would cause the error code 183, ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS, "Cannot create a file when that file already exists" ?

Comment: Are you using the Visual Studio hosting process? it might be running and grabbing the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio needs to be run as Administrator for IDE launches to have the correct permissions to create the named shared object.